# Can help me find the fft2d of an image using only fft1d in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

```
clear all;close all;clc;


Image = imread("aerial.tiff");

f = double(Image) ;


%2D DFT 
F1 = fft2(f);

M=size(f,1);
N=size(f,2);

for i = 1:N

 F2(i,:) = fft(f(i,:)); 

end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the MATLAB [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html#bvhcnas), the `fft2` is defined as:

- `fft` on the columns, followed by a `fft` on the rows.

Also, if you open the `fft2` code, you will find:

> ```
> f = fft(fft(x,[],2),[],1);
> ```

This code may help you:

```
clear;close all;clc;

Image = phantom(256);

f = double(Image);

%2D DFT 
F1 = fft2(f);

M=size(f,1);
N=size(f,2);

% 2D FFT by twice 1D FFT
F2 = fft(fft(f,[],2),[],1);

% Difference between the results
diff = F2 - F1;
[min(min(diff)) max(max(diff))]

subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(30.*log(abs(fftshift(F1)) + 1),[])
title('FFT using fft2')

subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(30.*log(abs(fftshift(F2)) + 1),[])
title('FFT using fft twice')
```

Comment: You should stop using `clear all`. It not only clears variables, but also all previously parsed functions, slowing down your code. The MATLAB Editor even warns you not to use it!